# C# : querying multiple columns into textboxes

Tags: c#, sql-server

This is my code, and I want to be able to search for a name, and then pull from the database the name, status, member_id into the textboxes in my form.

I got the name to work but how do I get the other columns and parse the output into the textboxes with the additional columns (member_id, status)? Let's say the other textboxes have the standard name such as textbox2, 3, 4...

```
string connetionString = null;
SqlConnection connection;
SqlCommand command;

string sql = null;
string sql1 = null;

SqlDataReader dataReader;

connetionString = "Data Source=......"
sql = "SELECT NAME FROM Test_Employee WHERE Name LIKE '" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "%'";
connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
{
    connection.Open();

    command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
    dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (dataReader.Read())
    {
        textBox9.Text = dataReader[0].ToString();
        textBox7.Text = dataReader[0].ToString();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: Is the _member_id_ and _status_ in the table `Test_Employee`? If it is, just modify your sql statement to `SELECT Name, Member_Id, Status..` and in your `while` block, add `textbox2.Text = datareader["member_id"]...`. Btw, you should consider refactoring your code because it is vulnerable to SQL injection. Try googling _c# sql command parameterization_.

Comment: @KristianneNerona: you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields *Member_Id* and *Status* also in the table *Test_Employee*? You can add them in your *Select* statement and get them from your *SqlReader*, like the code below (assuming you are using *c#7* and below). You may copy and paste this code.

```
var connectionString = "";
var sql = @"SELECT TOP 1 Name, Member_Id, Status
            FROM Test_Employee 
            WHERE Name LIKE @name + '%'";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = textBox1.Text.ToString();
    connection.Open();
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        textBox9.Text = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
        textBox7.Text = dataReader["Name"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = dataReader["Member_Id"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = dataReader["Status"].ToString();

    }
}
```

You will notice that instead of including the Textbox1.Text's value in your Select statement, it is added as a parameter in the *SQLCommand* object's `Parameters`. In this way your query is protected from *SQL Injection*. If you want to learn more, you can search *c# sqlcommand parameters* and why it is very important to build data access code this way.

Also, notice that I added `Top 1` in your Select statement, and instead of using `while`, I am using `if`. This is because a textbox can only hold 1 result at a time in a comprehensible way. If you meant to show multiple results clearly, you need to use a different control other than a TextBox.

The `using` statements allow you to dispose the connection, so you don't have to call `connection.Close()`.